# Reactance of an Inductor

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, inductance

The following video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbLhYniRGNw) derives an equation for the reactance of a capacitor. I am trying to derive the equation for reactance of an inductor.

Given an AC voltage drop $V(t)=V_osin (\omega t)$ in series with an inductor with inductance $L$.

> [I am trying to show $X_L=2\pi f L$.]

For an inductor, the voltage drop is $V_L=L\frac{di}{dt}$. By KVL, $V_L=V_osin(\omega t)$. Hence, $L\frac{di}{dt}=V_osin(\omega t)$. So, $\frac{di}{dt}=\frac{V_osin(\omega t)}{L}$. So, $\int \frac{di}{dt}dt = \int \frac{V_osin(\omega t)}{L} dt$. So, $I=\frac{-V_o cos(\omega t)}{\omega L}+C$. But this is where I get stuck...

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct so far.
But instead of $V(t)=V_0\sin(\omega t)$ start with $V(t)=V_0e^{j\omega t}$. And then repeat your calculation to find $I(t)$.

Comment: Is there a way to start with $V_0sin(\omega t)$? I am pretty new to this stuff and not that familiar with how Euler's formula relates to AC circuits. What does $V(t)=V_0 e^{j\omega t}$ stand for? I know that $V_0e^{j\omega t}=V_0(\cos(\omega t)+j\sin(\omega t))$. But what does that mean in context of AC circuits?

Comment: I was able to follow the proof here which makes sense: http://www.dzre.com/alex/HonorsPhysics/Calendars/HPNote_004.pdf

Comment: I just would like to know what the complex number thing means in the beginning.

Comment: @WilliamGarske The complex number thing $e^{j\omega t}$ is just a widely used
mathematical trick to avoid $\sin$ and $\cos$, thus making integration and derivation easier. See for example video [Why do we use complex numbers in circuit analyis?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gafnlatW8jw).

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=V_0\sin(\omega t)$.
For an inductor $V = \displaystyle  L\frac{dI}{dt} \Rightarrow \int V\,dt=V_0\int \sin(\omega t)\,dt= L\int dI $

$LI = -\dfrac{V_0}{\omega}\cos(\omega t) + \rm constant$ and you had a problem assigning a value for the constant of integration.

If $V_0 =0$ then $I=0$, ie there is no dc offset voltage, thus the constant of integration is zero.

$LI = -\dfrac{V_0}{\omega}\cos(\omega t)$

When $t=0,\, V=0, \,L\dfrac{dI}{dt}=0$ so the current against time graph is at a turning point.

$L\dfrac{d^2I}{dt^2} = \omega\,V_0\cos(\omega t)$, thus $\dfrac {d^2I}{dt^2}$ is positive at $t=0$ and thus the current is a minimum, $-I_0$

$L(-I_0)= -\dfrac {V_0}{\omega}\Rightarrow X_{\rm L}= \dfrac{V_0}{I_0} = \omega L$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just say $I=-\frac{V_0}{\omega} cos(\omega t)\implies I$ is a minimum at $t=0$? I don't think the second derivative test is entirely necessary but I could see it work for harder examples.

Comment: @WilliamGarske I agree but my thought was that since there was a struggle with the constant of proportionality I should also include the bit about the function being a minimum at $t=0$.

Comment: Do you know if this derivation holds true when $C\neq 0$? I am having a hard time understanding why $C=0$ for the reason why $V_0=0$ and $I=0$ as in my mind $V_0\neq 0$. If $C\neq 0$, we know $LI = -\dfrac{V_0}{\omega}\cos(\omega t) + C$ where $I$ is at a maximum at $t=\frac{\pi}{\omega}$. So, $L(I_0)=\frac{V_0}{\omega} + C\implies L=\frac{V_0}{I_0\omega}+\frac{C}{I_0}\implies L-\frac{C}{I_0}=\frac{V_0}{I_0 \omega}\implies \omega(L-\frac{C}{I_0})=\frac{V_0}{I_0}=X_L$

Comment: If there was a dc offset input voltage then its size would be the value of the integration constant.

Comment: Are you saying $C$ would be the value of the dc offset input voltage?

Comment: I just have a hard time wrapping my head around why $V_0$ could be made zero as it is the maximum voltage.